# Ultegra R8000 groupset want to convert to flat bar shifter

Tags: conversion, flatbar

I have searched but could not find any answers for my question.

I have the Ultegra R8000 mechanical rim brake group set on my road bike and I want to convert it to a flat bar setup.

I have searched and it shows that the [Shimano SL-RS700](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/105-5800/SL-RS700.html) flat bar 2x11 shifter from the 105 groupset work for the R8000? is this correct information? I don't want to purchase the shifters and brake levers if I end up not being able to use them.

Comment: Tiagra flat bar brake levers work well with Ultegra caliper brakes. They have the correct cable pull for caliper brakes.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't know that Shimano made 105 flat bar shifters and brake levers. Interesting.

Shimano road 11 speed groupsets use the same shift cable pull increment and derailleur actuation ratio, so the SL-RS700 shifters will work with Ultegra derailleurs.

The BL-R550 brake levers are obviously made to work with road caliper brakes. (Different brake systems have different cable pull and caliper leverage ratios. A set of levers for V-brakes for instance would not work with road calipers.)

One thing to be aware of is that replacing drop bars with flat bars is going to significantly reduce the reach geometry. If that is one of your goals that's fine, but if you have a good position when on the hoods of the drop bars your will probably find the flat bars cramped. You may need a long stem to get a good position.

frames for drop bars are generally have a shorter reach measured to the head tube than frames for flat bars. This is because drop bars add more reach than flat bars.

Comment: *replacing drop bars with flat bars is going to significantly reduce the reach geometry* If the goal is a more upright position, that actually works well, as moving the saddle back to maintain reach also results in a more upright position. But then bar *height* might become an issue. I'd hope the reason for changing to a flat bar isn't a belief that "flat bars are more comfortable", because that's not true. It's the upright *position*, for some. It can be just as easy to set up a drop-bar bike in an upright position. Flat bars on long rides can be "one hand position, all of them uncomfortable"

Comment: @AndrewHenle Agree, but should point out that saddle position should not be used to set reach. It should be used to set how far the riders feet are in front of their ass - which is mostly dictated by leg measurements.

Answer (score 1):

The Shifters will work, all Shimano road 11 speed front/rear derailleurs are compatible across generations and have same cable pull.

Comment: And the brake levers?

Comment: @DavidRicherby good point, Shimano rim brake nomenclature is confusing to say the least, I have no idea if cable pull is same enough between old Super SLR and newer SLR-EV, despite both being "short pull". I'd email Shimano with this question or try the combo at LBS.